# How to use public or internal class in JavaScript in Asp.Net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm working on asp.net web application. I want to use a class in javascript.
in asps.cs file we can easily use this like

```
ABC obj = new ABC();
obj.name = "John";
```

Can I use class in same manner in javascript?
If Yes then please tell me How to use public or internal class of same solution in JavaScript Code?

Comment: ScriptSharp is a library that lets you write c# code and have it compile into javascript. http://scriptsharp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't really have classes in the classic sense. There are [several workarounds available](http://www.phpied.com/3-ways-to-define-a-javascript-class/). A short overview:

1. Using a function
2. Using object literals
3. Singleton using a function

Note there won't really be a way of doing scope modifiers (public/internal/private etc).

You might look into [TypeScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typescript#Classes) and [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/#classes) both compile down to JavaScript, and supports classes. @asawyer pointed out the CoffeeScript idea.

It's worth noting that [ECMAScript 6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript#ECMAScript_Harmony_.286th_Edition.29) standard will include support for classes, however the specifications are still a work in progress.

Comment: In addition to this, coffeescript also adds Class support. http://coffeescript.org/#classes

Comment: Thanks for ur answer dear. But this is not what I want to implement.

Comment: @user3853187 The methods described in the link I provided all seem like valid solutions. How is this not what you want to implement?

Comment: If lets say there is a file ABC.cs in my solution. I'm currently in XYZ.aspx, in XYZ.aspx I want to use ABC Class. for example get ans set properties of ABC class.

Comment: @user3853187 (You should make it clearer in your question). Sorry, it doesn't work like that. Your server side classes reside on the server. You can transfer data back and forth, for example embedding some JSON on page load, or passing JSON back and forth via [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). But they're not directly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does have prototype support that can be used as classes as you know from the C# world.

```
// define a constructor of a class called "ABC"
function ABC() {
    this.name = null;
}

// create an instance of a class
var obj = new ABC();

// check instance property value
console.log(obj.name); // outputs "null"

// set instance property value
obj.name = "something";

// some more checks
console.log(obj.name); // outputs "something"
console.log(obj); // outputs whole object
```

And about public and internal/private classes they may be *simulated* within function scope (as Javascript only has function scope where C# has block scope as well).

Developers usually put their client logic inside a function, so they create a private scope and avoid any public name clashing or visibility of internal functionality. These scopes can then *publicise* whathever is required for the general public scope.

Any widely used client library is a great example of such pattern. jQuery or maybe even better AngularJS. It has a lot of internal business logic but just a handful of publically accessible functionality (variable `angular` being the main one).